# This program is about String Compression in java

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I am rookie in coding so please guide me in solving this.I set input string s from the user and declared StringBuilder sb and integer type variable consec

I am getting `IndexOutOfBound` exception here in the 'if' condition:

```
for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
    consec++;
    if(s.charAt(i)!=s.charAt(i+1) || i+1>=s.length()) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        sb.append(consec);
        consec=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `s.charAt(i+1)` is looking for a position longer than `s.length`

Comment: Hint: simply read the exception message. It actually tells you precisely what the problem is. You can also put that exception name into a search engine. It is really a super common problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java always evaluates left-to-right. So this:

```
s.charAt(i)!=s.charAt(i+1) || i+1>=s.length()
```

Evaluates `s.charAt(i+1)` before it has checked `i+1>=s.length()`. When `i+1 >= s.length()`, `s.charAt(i+1)` will fail, because it is beyond the end of the string.

Reverse the order of the operands:

```
i+1>=s.length() || s.charAt(i)!=s.charAt(i+1)
```

Because `||` is a short-circuiting operator, this only evaluates `s.charAt(i)!=s.charAt(i+1)` if `i+1>=s.length()` is false, so it doesn't fail with an exception in that case.

Answer (score 3):

It is because in last iteration of your loop you are accessing the element which is not in the array (index is higher than size of array), so try this:

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++){    //<<See this
    //your logic
}
```

When length of the String is even, you need to keep an edge case check explicitly after your `for` loop. For example,

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++){    //<<See this
    //your logic
}
if(s.length()%2==0){
    //your logic when length is even and loop has ignored last character.
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but when i input aabbbcc it outputs a2b3 it ignores c

Comment: For that you have to keep an extra check after your loop if the length of the string is even.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a string,

```
String s = "abcd";
```

Your loop will run from 0 - > s.length()-1, i.e from 0 -> 3
So when you will be at index 3,`i+1=4` 
so, s.charAt(i+1) will throw out of bounds exception, since 4 is higher than array index. Therefore either run loop from `i -> 0 to i < s.length()-1`. Or change your existing code to the following:

```
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    consec++;
    if(i+1<s.length() && s.charAt(i)!=s.charAt(i+1))
    {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        sb.append(consec);
        consec=0;
    }
}
```